# Segmentation fault when accessing strings from linked list

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am trying to write a program that counts how many times a word is used in a text document. To do this I created a function called wordList that creates a linked list with a node for each word. Unfortunately, whenever I try to read a word from the linked list with printf there is a segmentation fault. I believe this is because the linked list is not actually copying any of the words. I am wondering how I can resolve this issue. At the moment I do not know how to proceed. Thanks:)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Node {
        int timesUsed;
        char* word;
        struct Node* next;
};

struct Node* wordList(FILE *fp, struct Node* head);
struct Node* createNode(struct Node* head, char* word);
char* title(char* file);//creates file name based on command line input


int main(int argc, char** argv){
    //Access file information---------------------------------------------
    FILE *fp;
    char* fileName = title(argv[1]);
    fp = fopen(fileName, "r");

    //Define Head node--------------------------------------------------------

    struct Node* head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    if (head == NULL){
        printf("there is not enough memory on your device to continue\n");
    }
    //Access words--------------------------------------------------------

    head = wordList(fp, head);
    printf("%s\n",head->word);


    free(head);
    free(fileName);
    return 0;
}


//Function that is causing problems==================================
struct Node* wordList(FILE *fp, struct Node* head){
    char c;
    char wordHolder[1240];//characters
    int j = 0;
    int count = 0;

    do{
    c = getc(fp);
    printf("%c\n",c);
    if(isalpha(c) || isdigit(c) || c == '\''){
        wordHolder[j] = c;
        j++;
    }
    else{
        if(count){
            char* tempWord = strdup(wordHolder);
            head->word = tempWord;
            head->timesUsed = 1;
            head->next = NULL;
                count = 1;
                j = 0;
                for(i = 0; i< strlen(wordHolder); i++){
                    wordHolder[i] = '\0';
                }
            }

            else{
                head = createNode(head, wordHolder);
                j = 0;
                for(i = 0; i< strlen(wordHolder); i++){
                    wordHolder[i] = '\0';
                }

            }
        }       
    }
    while(c != EOF);
    return head;
}

//Creates a new node at end of list=====================================
struct Node* createNode(struct Node* head, char* word){
    struct Node* temp = head;

    while(temp != NULL){
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->timesUsed = 1;
    char* tempWord = strdup(word);
    temp->word = tempWord;
    temp->next = NULL;

    return head;
}


//Creates fileName======================================
char* title(char* file){
    char nameOfFile[500];
    strcpy(nameOfFile, file);
    strcat(nameOfFile, ".txt");
    char* temp;
    temp = strdup(nameOfFile);

    if(temp == NULL){
        printf("Your computer has litte memory.\n");
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: `wordHolder` is not null-terminated when either `strdup` or `strlen` is called.

Comment: I changed the declaration of wordHolder to:    
     



char wordHolder[1240] = {'\0'};

It still failed

Comment: We are not chasing moving goalposts here. Post your actual code and leave it as is.

Comment: Fill the entire array with zeros, after declaration.

Comment: It workded. Thanks. However, it only prints out NULL:(

Comment: where is count incremented?  Also, you need to update wordHolder before you update your new node